# Target Woocommerce order received page with my CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, css-selectors

In WooCommerce, I created a special header in the Checkout page.

After the order is submited the next step will be `/checkout/order-received/`page.

Is there any special CSS class for the order-received page?
Is there something like `#order-received`?

Answer (score 4):

To target order-received page with your CSS you will use the body class `woocommerce-order-received`… so your related CSS selectors should all start with:

```
body.woocommerce-order-received
```